# Why are Visual Studio 2010 VB and C# debug outputs different for identical COM project?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, catia

I apologize if this issue has already been explained but I have searched and not found an answer that I can comprehend. I have been using VB.Net for years to automate CATIA by adding their libraries and calling the exposed methods, properties, etc. I wrote some some basic code to C#.Net and was disappointed to find that the objects are not exposed in the same way as they are in VB. What I mean is when an object is examined in the debugger or watch window, the properties are not displayed in C#, but they are displayed in VB. This makes it pretty much impossible for me to debug CATIA automation in C#, which doesn't seem right. Something must be missing. I have added the COM libraries to the project and have Included them in the header properly. The intellisense is working and the basic methods of the CATIA objects are visible in the watch/debug but not all methods and properties are visible and I can't interrogate them by manually typing a object.get_Name() or something like that in the debug window.
I've attached images of two watch window results for identical code. The first is from VB.Net and you can see how much more information is available. The second is from C#.Net and you can see how little information is available. How can I access the same level of information in the C# debugger that I see in the VB debugger for COM interop assemblies? One thing I noticed that may be a clue here is that in VB, there are many object properties which appeared as get_ methods in C#. For example, the property Document.Name in VB is found as Document.get_Name() in C#.

OK, so the site won't allow me to post images since I "need at least 10 reputation points." Hopefully there's enough problem description to go on.

Comment: You can't post images directly, but you can still post links to the images, as well as inserting the code that is giving you trouble. Also you might want to break up your wall of text into paragraphs. See [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but if you go into Tools > Options > C#, is "Hide advanced members" checked?